# Find the orthogonal decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_1=(2, 2, 3,1)$ and $v_2=(—3,1,1,1)$.

$V = span\{v_1,v_2\}$

Let $w = (1,17,4,6)$. Find the orthogonal decomposition of w with respect to V in the form $v + u$, where $v \in V$ and $u \in V^\bot$

By finding the null space of V, I could find $V^\bot$,

$V^\bot=span\{(-1,-11,8,0),(1,-5,0,8)\}$

The only problem for me is to find the orthogonal decomposition of w in the form of $v + u$, since using the formula to calculate $proj_vw$ and  I got $w=(57,79,35,5)$ is a vector not a combination of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are orthogonal then

$$v= (v_1\cdot w)\frac{v_1}{|v_1|}+(v_2\cdot w)\frac{v_2}{|v_2|}$$

and $u=w-v$.